# Email commiter of a bad Perforce Changelist through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce

How can I email the commiter of a broken change using a Perforce Changelist number in Jenkins?

Basically I have the CL available to me, but I cant quite figure out how to get the commiter name and other Perforce metadata info based off of that CL and then send out an email.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried 'p4 change -o CL', or 'p4 describe -s CL'? Those should both give you the committer name and other Perforce metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You should install "Email-ext" plugin for Jenkins. It allows you to send editable email notification for different build status. 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin
As it captures the content token and P4 meta-data, you can configure (from "Advance" option in jenkins, after the plug-in is installed) whom (committer, requester, recipient list, culprit etc) do you want to send the notification.

Comment: Add "culprits" from Send to options. Its the user responsible for perforce change.